# Adding foreignObjects to D3 force-directed graph nodes breaks events

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I'm currently learning D3 visualization.
While working on a force-directed graph where I needed to show country flags on nodes (lots of them, for all countries), I decided to go for a single png background and CSS spritesheet to decrease the number of requests to server.
Since svg elements cannot have *background-position* property and thus cannot be styled via a CSS spritesheet, I decided to add a foreignObject element to each node, and style that instead.

The way I do it is by making each node a g element and adding a foreignObject to it:

```
var node = svg.selectAll('node')
.data(json.nodes)
.enter().append('g')
.attr('class', 'node')
.call(force.drag())

var fo = node.append("foreignObject")
```

Then I set the css class in the tick function:

```
force.on('tick', function() { 
if (force.alpha()<0.3) {
   fo        
    .attr('height', w/100)
    .attr("width",w/70)
    .attr("class", function(d){
  return "flag flag-" + d.code
}) //CSS sprite
    .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; })
```

The styles themselves are set via the following CSS:

```
.flag {
width: 16px;
height: 11px;
background-image:url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8_3FL-6NZmAeXdJdlJ0REVzRWs") 
}
.flag.flag-ad {background-position: -16px 0}
.flag.flag-ae {background-position: -32px 0}
etc.
```

It worked, meaning that I got the flags on my nodes (see the example at https://codepen.io/SergeySS/pen/qNzbyA), but it also broke every node event I was using (drag,mouseover/out/move; I suppose any other events would be broken as well). 
The issue is clearly with the foreignObject. When I substitute the foreignObject with a rect, the events fire normally (although, of course, I get just a bunch of identical rectangles instead of my flags).

```
//var fo = node.append("rect")
```

There are no errors in both scenarios, it's just that the events are not firing.

I wonder why is that happening?

I have managed to solve the task by reverting to svg images and using individual images via xlink:href property (see the complete example at http://codepen.io/SergeySS/pen/yJdBmz).

```
var fo = node.append("image")

if (force.alpha()<0.3) {
    fo        
        .attr('height', w/100)
        .attr("width",w/70)
        .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("xlink:href",function(d){
        return "http://hewgill.com/flags/"+d.code+".svg"
    })
```

Still, this question is relevant for me because:

1. the svg images solution results in a lot of calls to the server
   while fetching images
2. I believe that there are other use cases for
   inserting HTML objects into svg
3. This is weird behaviour,which usually means that either there's a bug, or I am doing something wrong, and I'd like to find out which it is.

So, if anyone can tell me **why appending a foreignObject to a D3 force-directed graph node breaks all events of that node**, I'll be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

I was hesitant to type up this up as an answer because it's *not an answer to your question* but instead a better way to do what you want.  Essentially, the `foreignObject` tag is evil and should never be used.

So the new quesiton becomes how can we replicate CSS style sprites with SVG?  The answer is SVG fill patterns in all their glory.

Say we take your css background image definitions and reformat to a JavaScript array:

```
var imagePos = [{
      name: "ad",
      x: 16,
      y: 0
    }, {
      name: "ae",
      x: 32,
      y: 0
    }, 
    ...
 ];
```

And create a pattern for each flag:

```
var defs = svg.append("defs")
  .selectAll("pattern")
  .data(imagePos)
  .enter()
  .append("pattern")
  .attr("width", 16)
  .attr("height", 11)
  .attr("patternTransform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + -d.x + "," + -d.y + ")";
  })
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return "pattern_" + d.name;
  });

defs.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8_3FL-6NZmAeXdJdlJ0REVzRWs")
  .attr("width", "256")
  .attr("height", "176");
```

We can then fill our nodes like:

```
var node = svg.selectAll('node')
  .data(json.nodes)
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .call(force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", function() {
      bDragging = true
    })
    .on("dragend", function() {
      bDragging = false
    }));

node.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 16)
  .attr("height", 11)
  .style("stroke", "none")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "url(#pattern_" + d.code + ")";
  });
```

And **BAM** we have no more `foreignObject` and only one image to download.

**Note**, I rewrote your `tick` function, it should operate on the nodes.

---

Updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyByrB)

---

Running code:

```js
//var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 22,20,21,5];

var w = 0;
var h = 0;
var barPadding = 0;
var padding = 70
var svgOffset = 100
var circleRadius = 10
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
var xScale, yScale, colorScale, svg, baseTemp
var yearBarWidth, yearBarHeight
var minYear, maxYear
var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DealPete/forceDirected/master/countries.json"
var heatMap = [];
var tooltip = d3.select(".my-tooltip")
var force = d3.layout.force();
var bDragging = false

d3.json(url, processJson);

function processJson(json) {
  initializeViewBox();
  //prepJson(json);
  initializeForce(json);
  drawNodesAndLinks(json);
  force.start()
  console.log("done processing json")
}

function initializeViewBox() {
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = w * 0.6;
  
  svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("class", "svg-content")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  //.attr("heigth",h)
  //.attr("width",w)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
  
}

function initializeForce(json) {
console.log("initializing force,",force)
  force 
    .size([w, h])
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    //.linkDistance(w/2.5)
    .gravity(0.3)
    .charge(-400);
 // d3.forceCollide(w/200)
}
function prepJson(json){
  for (var i=0; i<json.nodes.length;i++){
json.nodes[i].x = w*Math.random()
json.nodes[i].y = w*Math.random()
  }
 console.log(json.nodes)
}
function drawNodesAndLinks(json) {
  
  var imagePos = [
{name: "ad", x: 16, y: 0},
{name: "ae", x: 32, y: 0},
{name: "af", x: 48, y: 0},
{name: "ag", x: 64, y: 0},
{name: "ai", x: 80, y: 0},
{name: "al", x: 96, y: 0},
{name: "am", x: 112, y: 0},
{name: "an", x: 128, y: 0},
{name: "ao", x: 144, y: 0},
{name: "ar", x: 160, y: 0},
{name: "as", x: 176, y: 0},
{name: "at", x: 192, y: 0},
{name: "au", x: 208, y: 0},
{name: "aw", x: 224, y: 0},
{name: "az", x: 240, y: 0},
{name: "ba", x: 0, y: 11},
{name: "bb", x: 16, y: 11},
{name: "bd", x: 32, y: 11},
{name: "be", x: 48, y: 11},
{name: "bf", x: 64, y: 11},
{name: "bg", x: 80, y: 11},
{name: "bh", x: 96, y: 11},
{name: "bi", x: 112, y: 11},
{name: "bj", x: 128, y: 11},
{name: "bm", x: 144, y: 11},
{name: "bn", x: 160, y: 11},
{name: "bo", x: 176, y: 11},
{name: "br", x: 192, y: 11},
{name: "bs", x: 208, y: 11},
{name: "bt", x: 224, y: 11},
{name: "bv", x: 240, y: 11},
{name: "bw", x: 0, y: 22},
{name: "by", x: 16, y: 22},
{name: "bz", x: 32, y: 22},
{name: "ca", x: 48, y: 22},
{name: "catalonia", x: 64, y: 22},
{name: "cd", x: 80, y: 22},
{name: "cf", x: 96, y: 22},
{name: "cg", x: 112, y: 22},
{name: "ch", x: 128, y: 22},
{name: "ci", x: 144, y: 22},
{name: "ck", x: 160, y: 22},
{name: "cl", x: 176, y: 22},
{name: "cm", x: 192, y: 22},
{name: "cn", x: 208, y: 22},
{name: "co", x: 224, y: 22},
{name: "cr", x: 240, y: 22},
{name: "cu", x: 0, y: 33},
{name: "cv", x: 16, y: 33},
{name: "cw", x: 32, y: 33},
{name: "cy", x: 48, y: 33},
{name: "cz", x: 64, y: 33},
{name: "de", x: 80, y: 33},
{name: "dj", x: 96, y: 33},
{name: "dk", x: 112, y: 33},
{name: "dm", x: 128, y: 33},
{name: "do", x: 144, y: 33},
{name: "dz", x: 160, y: 33},
{name: "ec", x: 176, y: 33},
{name: "ee", x: 192, y: 33},
{name: "eg", x: 208, y: 33},
{name: "eh", x: 224, y: 33},
{name: "england", x: 240, y: 33},
{name: "er", x: 0, y: 44},
{name: "es", x: 16, y: 44},
{name: "et", x: 32, y: 44},
{name: "eu", x: 48, y: 44},
{name: "fi", x: 64, y: 44},
{name: "fj", x: 80, y: 44},
{name: "fk", x: 96, y: 44},
{name: "fm", x: 112, y: 44},
{name: "fo", x: 128, y: 44},
{name: "fr", x: 144, y: 44},
{name: "ga", x: 160, y: 44},
{name: "gb", x: 176, y: 44},
{name: "gd", x: 192, y: 44},
{name: "ge", x: 208, y: 44},
{name: "gf", x: 224, y: 44},
{name: "gg", x: 240, y: 44},
{name: "gh", x: 0, y: 55},
{name: "gi", x: 16, y: 55},
{name: "gl", x: 32, y: 55},
{name: "gm", x: 48, y: 55},
{name: "gn", x: 64, y: 55},
{name: "gp", x: 80, y: 55},
{name: "gq", x: 96, y: 55},
{name: "gr", x: 112, y: 55},
{name: "gs", x: 128, y: 55},
{name: "gt", x: 144, y: 55},
{name: "gu", x: 160, y: 55},
{name: "gw", x: 176, y: 55},
{name: "gy", x: 192, y: 55},
{name: "hk", x: 208, y: 55},
{name: "hm", x: 224, y: 55},
{name: "hn", x: 240, y: 55},
{name: "hr", x: 0, y: 66},
{name: "ht", x: 16, y: 66},
{name: "hu", x: 32, y: 66},
{name: "ic", x: 48, y: 66},
{name: "id", x: 64, y: 66},
{name: "ie", x: 80, y: 66},
{name: "il", x: 96, y: 66},
{name: "im", x: 112, y: 66},
{name: "in", x: 128, y: 66},
{name: "io", x: 144, y: 66},
{name: "iq", x: 160, y: 66},
{name: "ir", x: 176, y: 66},
{name: "is", x: 192, y: 66},
{name: "it", x: 208, y: 66},
{name: "je", x: 224, y: 66},
{name: "jm", x: 240, y: 66},
{name: "jo", x: 0, y: 77},
{name: "jp", x: 16, y: 77},
{name: "ke", x: 32, y: 77},
{name: "kg", x: 48, y: 77},
{name: "kh", x: 64, y: 77},
{name: "ki", x: 80, y: 77},
{name: "km", x: 96, y: 77},
{name: "kn", x: 112, y: 77},
{name: "kp", x: 128, y: 77},
{name: "kr", x: 144, y: 77},
{name: "kurdistan", x: 160, y: 77},
{name: "kw", x: 176, y: 77},
{name: "ky", x: 192, y: 77},
{name: "kz", x: 208, y: 77},
{name: "la", x: 224, y: 77},
{name: "lb", x: 240, y: 77},
{name: "lc", x: 0, y: 88},
{name: "li", x: 16, y: 88},
{name: "lk", x: 32, y: 88},
{name: "lr", x: 48, y: 88},
{name: "ls", x: 64, y: 88},
{name: "lt", x: 80, y: 88},
{name: "lu", x: 96, y: 88},
{name: "lv", x: 112, y: 88},
{name: "ly", x: 128, y: 88},
{name: "ma", x: 144, y: 88},
{name: "mc", x: 160, y: 88},
{name: "md", x: 176, y: 88},
{name: "me", x: 192, y: 88},
{name: "mg", x: 208, y: 88},
{name: "mh", x: 224, y: 88},
{name: "mk", x: 240, y: 88},
{name: "ml", x: 0, y: 99},
{name: "mm", x: 16, y: 99},
{name: "mn", x: 32, y: 99},
{name: "mo", x: 48, y: 99},
{name: "mp", x: 64, y: 99},
{name: "mq", x: 80, y: 99},
{name: "mr", x: 96, y: 99},
{name: "ms", x: 112, y: 99},
{name: "mt", x: 128, y: 99},
{name: "mu", x: 144, y: 99},
{name: "mv", x: 160, y: 99},
{name: "mw", x: 176, y: 99},
{name: "mx", x: 192, y: 99},
{name: "my", x: 208, y: 99},
{name: "mz", x: 224, y: 99},
{name: "na", x: 240, y: 99},
{name: "nc", x: 0, y: 110},
{name: "ne", x: 16, y: 110},
{name: "nf", x: 32, y: 110},
{name: "ng", x: 48, y: 110},
{name: "ni", x: 64, y: 110},
{name: "nl", x: 80, y: 110},
{name: "no", x: 96, y: 110},
{name: "np", x: 112, y: 110},
{name: "nr", x: 128, y: 110},
{name: "nu", x: 144, y: 110},
{name: "nz", x: 160, y: 110},
{name: "om", x: 176, y: 110},
{name: "pa", x: 192, y: 110},
{name: "pe", x: 208, y: 110},
{name: "pf", x: 224, y: 110},
{name: "pg", x: 240, y: 110},
{name: "ph", x: 0, y: 121},
{name: "pk", x: 16, y: 121},
{name: "pl", x: 32, y: 121},
{name: "pm", x: 48, y: 121},
{name: "pn", x: 64, y: 121},
{name: "pr", x: 80, y: 121},
{name: "ps", x: 96, y: 121},
{name: "pt", x: 112, y: 121},
{name: "pw", x: 128, y: 121},
{name: "py", x: 144, y: 121},
{name: "qa", x: 160, y: 121},
{name: "re", x: 176, y: 121},
{name: "ro", x: 192, y: 121},
{name: "rs", x: 208, y: 121},
{name: "ru", x: 224, y: 121},
{name: "rw", x: 240, y: 121},
{name: "sa", x: 0, y: 132},
{name: "sb", x: 16, y: 132},
{name: "sc", x: 32, y: 132},
{name: "scotland", x: 48, y: 132},
{name: "sd", x: 64, y: 132},
{name: "se", x: 80, y: 132},
{name: "sg", x: 96, y: 132},
{name: "sh", x: 112, y: 132},
{name: "si", x: 128, y: 132},
{name: "sk", x: 144, y: 132},
{name: "sl", x: 160, y: 132},
{name: "sm", x: 176, y: 132},
{name: "sn", x: 192, y: 132},
{name: "so", x: 208, y: 132},
{name: "somaliland", x: 224, y: 132},
{name: "sr", x: 240, y: 132},
{name: "ss", x: 0, y: 143},
{name: "st", x: 16, y: 143},
{name: "sv", x: 32, y: 143},
{name: "sx", x: 48, y: 143},
{name: "sy", x: 64, y: 143},
{name: "sz", x: 80, y: 143},
{name: "tc", x: 96, y: 143},
{name: "td", x: 112, y: 143},
{name: "tf", x: 128, y: 143},
{name: "tg", x: 144, y: 143},
{name: "th", x: 160, y: 143},
{name: "tibet", x: 176, y: 143},
{name: "tj", x: 192, y: 143},
{name: "tk", x: 208, y: 143},
{name: "tl", x: 224, y: 143},
{name: "tm", x: 240, y: 143},
{name: "tn", x: 0, y: 154},
{name: "to", x: 16, y: 154},
{name: "tr", x: 32, y: 154},
{name: "tt", x: 48, y: 154},
{name: "tv", x: 64, y: 154},
{name: "tw", x: 80, y: 154},
{name: "tz", x: 96, y: 154},
{name: "ua", x: 112, y: 154},
{name: "ug", x: 128, y: 154},
{name: "um", x: 144, y: 154},
{name: "us", x: 160, y: 154},
{name: "uy", x: 176, y: 154},
{name: "uz", x: 192, y: 154},
{name: "va", x: 208, y: 154},
{name: "vc", x: 224, y: 154},
{name: "ve", x: 240, y: 154},
{name: "vg", x: 0, y: 165},
{name: "vi", x: 16, y: 165},
{name: "vn", x: 32, y: 165},
{name: "vu", x: 48, y: 165},
{name: "wales", x: 64, y: 165},
{name: "wf", x: 80, y: 165},
{name: "ws", x: 96, y: 165},
{name: "xk", x: 112, y: 165},
{name: "ye", x: 128, y: 165},
{name: "yt", x: 144, y: 165},
{name: "za", x: 160, y: 165},
{name: "zanzibar", x: 176, y: 165},
{name: "zm", x: 192, y: 165},
{name: "zw", x: 208, y: 165}
];
  
  var defs = svg.append("defs")
    .selectAll("pattern")
    .data(imagePos)
    .enter()
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 11)
    .attr("id", function(d){
      return "pattern_" + d.name;
  });
  
  defs.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8_3FL-6NZmAeXdJdlJ0REVzRWs")
    .attr("x", function(d){
      return -d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d){
      return -d.y;
    })
    .attr("width", "256")
    .attr("height", "176");
  
  var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(json.links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link');

 var node = svg.selectAll('node')
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .call(force.drag()
          .on("dragstart",function(){
      bDragging = true
    })
         .on("dragend",function(){bDragging=false}))
 
///PROBLEM HERE!!

 
 //var fo = node.append("rect") //events working, but no css sprite possible
node.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 16)
  .attr("height", 11)
  .style("stroke", "none")
  .attr("fill", function(d){
    return "url(#pattern_" + d.code + ")";
  })
 
 //css spritesheet, but events are disabled
 //var fo = node.append("image") //separate svg images, events working, but lots of server calls - for each image

  force.on('tick', function() { 
  
    if (force.alpha()<0.3) {
      /*
    fo        
        .attr('height', w/100)
        .attr("width",w/70)
        .attr("class", function(d){
      return "flag flag-" + d.code
    }) //CSS sprite
        .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; })
   //     .attr("xlink:href",function(d){
    //    return "http://hewgill.com/flags/"+d.code+".svg"
 //   }) // SVG images
       */
    node.attr("transform", function(d){
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
      
    link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  }
  
});
  
 node.on("mouseover",function(d) {
    if (!bDragging) {
      d3.select(".my-popup").html(d.country)
    d3.select(".my-popup").classed("hidden",false)
    }
    
 })
         .on("mousemove",function(d){
          
            d3.select(".my-popup").style('top', (d3.event.layerY + padding*2 + 5) + 'px')
        .style('left', (d3.event.layerX  + padding + 5) + 'px')
        })
        .on("mouseout",function(d){
                      d3.select(".my-popup").classed("hidden", true);

        })
}

function xdragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x, d.fy = d.y;
}

function xdragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x, d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function xdragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null, d.fy = null;
}











function drawLegend() {
  //get color values

  var arrThresholds = [];
  var dom = colorScale.domain()
  var len = (dom[0] - dom[1]) / colorScale.range().length
  colorScale.range().map(function(item, index) {
    console.log(index * len + "-" + (index + 1) * len, item)
    arrThresholds.push([index * len, (index + 1) * len])
  })

  var legendRectSize = 20;
  var legendSpacing = 2;
  var startX = w * 8 / 9;
  var startY = h - padding + 35;
  var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend') // NEW
    .data(colorScale.range()) // NEW
    .enter() // NEW
    .append('g') // NEW
    .attr('class', 'legend')
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      //console.log(d)
      return d
    }) // NEW
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) { // NEW
      var horz = startX - i * (legendRectSize + legendSpacing);
      return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + startY + ')'; // NEW
    }); // NEW
  legend.append('rect') // NEW
    .attr('width', legendRectSize) // NEW
    .attr('height', legendRectSize) // NEW
    .style('fill', colorScale) // NEW
    .style('stroke', colorScale)
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      d3.select(".my-popup").html(arrThresholds[colorScale.range().length - 1 - i][0] + "-" + arrThresholds[colorScale.range().length - 1 - i][1] + "&deg;C")

      d3.select(".my-popup").classed("hidden", false)

    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      d3.select(".my-popup").style('top', (d3.event.layerY + padding * 2 + 20) + 'px')
        .style('left', (d3.event.layerX + padding + 20) + 'px')
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(".my-popup").classed("hidden", true);

    })
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", startX + 25)
    .attr("y", startY + legendRectSize / 1.5)
    .text("hotter")

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", startX - colorScale.range().length * legendRectSize - 40)
    .attr("y", startY + legendRectSize / 1.5)
    .text("colder")
    // NEW
    //svg.append('rect').transform("translate(300,300)")
}

function round(number, decimals) {
  return +(Math.round(number + "e+" + decimals) + "e-" + decimals);
}
// NEW
```

```css
.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  color: grey;
}
.subtitle {
  @extend .title;
  font-size: medium;
}
.circle {
  stroke: grey;
}


svg .bar {
  padding: 1px;
  margin: auto;
  fill: blue;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.yAxis {
  @extend .axis;
}
.yAxis path,line {
  stroke: none;
}
.axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.my-tooltip {
  background: rgba(250,250,250,0.95);
  border-radius: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
  color: grey;
  left: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 60px;
  //width: 350px;
  display: block;
}
.my-tooltip.hidden {
  display:none
}
.tooltip-allegation {
  font-size: small;
  color:black;
  font-style: italic;
}
.tooltip-time {
  font-size: medium
}
.tooltip-name {
  font-size: large
}
.my-popup {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
  color: black;
  left: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 60px;
  //width: 210px;
  display: block;
}
.my-popup.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.desc {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: x-small;
  color: blue;
  //width: 1000px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
}
.svg-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.svg-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 158, 150, 0.8)
}
.sources,.note{
  font-style: italic;
}
.node {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link {
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer, Mark! This obviously solves the original problem. I ran across this pattern thing once, but thought it was too complicated to implement. Now I see it's actually fine.

Comment: One thing that disturbs me though is that **some** of the flags in your example turn out wrong (not that I'm complaining, mind you). Eg the US flag produced by css .flag.flag-us {background-position: -160px -154px} and pattern {name: "us", x: 160, y: 154} is the same, while the RU flag via pattern {name: "ru", x: 224, y: 121} is different from CSS .flag.flag-ru {background-position: -224px -121px}. Must be something I don't understand about the pattern specification yet.

Comment: @SergeySS To try to fix your problem: instead of applying a `patternTransform` onto the `pattern`, apply a `transform` onto the `image` with the same value from the `patternTransform`.

Comment: @SergeySS, my apologies I never saw your comment.  Looking back over this question, answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696831/d3-force-directed-graph-why-dont-the-flags-appear/43699769), I fixed your issue above.  `not satan` is correct, the `patternTransform` does some strange wrapping after 100 pixels.