# D3 Force Directed Graph: why don't the flags appear?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**SITUATION:**

Each `node` should have it's corresponding flag on it, that is not the case.

---

**CODE:**

```css
body {
    font-family: Lato;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.title {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#results {
    text-align: center;
}

#results div {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#results {
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    padding: 40px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}

/*!
 * Generated with CSS Flag Sprite generator (https://www.flag-sprites.com/)
 */

.flag {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 11px;
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/gMUNBQ/flags.png") no-repeat;
}


.flag.flag-td {
    background-position: -240px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-pw {
    background-position: 0 -121px;
}

.flag.flag-fk {
    background-position: -32px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-im {
    background-position: -48px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-fr {
    background-position: -80px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-sh {
    background-position: -240px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-bg {
    background-position: -64px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-ly {
    background-position: -48px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-tk {
    background-position: -64px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-re {
    background-position: -48px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-nl {
    background-position: -240px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-sv {
    background-position: -160px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-sa {
    background-position: -128px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-ck {
    background-position: -128px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-tr {
    background-position: -144px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-pr {
    background-position: -224px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-tv {
    background-position: -176px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-sd {
    background-position: -192px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-uy {
    background-position: -16px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-bb {
    background-position: 0 -11px;
}

.flag.flag-za {
    background-position: -256px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-vu {
    background-position: -144px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-ba {
    background-position: -256px 0;
}

.flag.flag-kr {
    background-position: -80px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-tf {
    background-position: -256px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-cl {
    background-position: -144px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-ki {
    background-position: -16px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-lr {
    background-position: -240px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-do {
    background-position: -96px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-dz {
    background-position: -112px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-cr {
    background-position: -208px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-ar {
    background-position: -144px 0;
}

.flag.flag-sb {
    background-position: -144px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-tj {
    background-position: -48px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-cw {
    background-position: -256px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-bv {
    background-position: -224px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-pn {
    background-position: -208px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-so {
    background-position: -80px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-la {
    background-position: -160px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-me {
    background-position: -112px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-sx {
    background-position: -176px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-sy {
    background-position: -192px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-gq {
    background-position: -32px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-ro {
    background-position: -64px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-kurdistan {
    background-position: -96px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-si {
    background-position: -256px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-mh {
    background-position: -144px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-ky {
    background-position: -128px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-eh {
    background-position: -176px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-ru {
    background-position: -96px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-tz {
    background-position: -208px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-np {
    background-position: 0 -110px;
}

.flag.flag-pg {
    background-position: -128px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-lb {
    background-position: -176px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-sn {
    background-position: -64px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-gw {
    background-position: -112px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-tt {
    background-position: -160px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-eg {
    background-position: -160px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-gn {
    background-position: 0 -55px;
}

.flag.flag-al {
    background-position: -80px 0;
}

.flag.flag-jm {
    background-position: -192px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-be {
    background-position: -32px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-kn {
    background-position: -48px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-mu {
    background-position: -48px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-az {
    background-position: -240px 0;
}

.flag.flag-gh {
    background-position: -208px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-vg {
    background-position: -96px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-ug {
    background-position: -240px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-rw {
    background-position: -112px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-pl {
    background-position: -176px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-at {
    background-position: -176px 0;
}

.flag.flag-bs {
    background-position: -192px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-ee {
    background-position: -144px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-no {
    background-position: -256px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-ca {
    background-position: -16px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-ml {
    background-position: -176px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-vc {
    background-position: -64px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-mc {
    background-position: -80px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-vi {
    background-position: -112px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-fj {
    background-position: -16px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-sj {
    background-position: 0 -132px;
}

.flag.flag-ic {
    background-position: -240px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-fo {
    background-position: -64px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-lu {
    background-position: -16px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-nf {
    background-position: -192px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-mm {
    background-position: -192px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-er {
    background-position: -208px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-somaliland {
    background-position: -96px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-lc {
    background-position: -192px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-cd {
    background-position: -48px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-ma {
    background-position: -64px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-mp {
    background-position: -240px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-mx {
    background-position: -96px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-na {
    background-position: -144px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-gs {
    background-position: -64px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-tw {
    background-position: -192px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-ae {
    background-position: -16px 0;
}

.flag.flag-cu {
    background-position: -224px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-id {
    background-position: -256px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-ht {
    background-position: -208px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-kw {
    background-position: -112px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-by {
    background-position: -256px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-il {
    background-position: -16px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-ps {
    background-position: -240px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-tl {
    background-position: -80px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-ai {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

.flag.flag-gp {
    background-position: -16px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-pt {
    background-position: -256px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-gr {
    background-position: -48px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-bw {
    background-position: -240px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-kp {
    background-position: -64px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-mq {
    background-position: -256px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-ad {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.flag.flag-gu {
    background-position: -96px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-cf {
    background-position: -64px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-ni {
    background-position: -224px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-ke {
    background-position: -240px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-mz {
    background-position: -128px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-kh {
    background-position: 0 -77px;
}

.flag.flag-us {
    background-position: 0 -154px;
}

.flag.flag-wf {
    background-position: -176px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-hk {
    background-position: -144px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-ph {
    background-position: -144px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-de {
    background-position: -32px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-sc {
    background-position: -160px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-tibet {
    background-position: -32px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-cy {
    background-position: 0 -33px;
}

.flag.flag-scotland {
    background-position: -176px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-ws {
    background-position: -192px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-ci {
    background-position: -112px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-bf {
    background-position: -48px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-tn {
    background-position: -112px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-my {
    background-position: -112px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-mw {
    background-position: -80px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-an {
    background-position: -112px 0;
}

.flag.flag-nr {
    background-position: -16px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-pm {
    background-position: -192px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-xk {
    background-position: -208px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-es {
    background-position: -224px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-pa {
    background-position: -80px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-jp {
    background-position: -224px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-mr {
    background-position: 0 -99px;
}

.flag.flag-pf {
    background-position: -112px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-cn {
    background-position: -176px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-au {
    background-position: -192px 0;
}

.flag.flag-cv {
    background-position: -240px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-ao {
    background-position: -128px 0;
}

.flag.flag-fi {
    background-position: 0 -44px;
}

.flag.flag-nc {
    background-position: -160px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-ag {
    background-position: -48px 0;
}

.flag.flag-gy {
    background-position: -128px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-nu {
    background-position: -32px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-to {
    background-position: -128px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-qa {
    background-position: -32px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-dm {
    background-position: -80px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-aw {
    background-position: -208px 0;
}

.flag.flag-cz {
    background-position: -16px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-mk {
    background-position: -160px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-ax {
    background-position: -224px 0;
}

.flag.flag-pk {
    background-position: -160px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-st {
    background-position: -144px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-bz {
    background-position: 0 -22px;
}

.flag.flag-br {
    background-position: -176px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-am {
    background-position: -96px 0;
}

.flag.flag-bh {
    background-position: -80px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-gg {
    background-position: -192px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-um {
    background-position: -256px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-ga {
    background-position: -96px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-yt {
    background-position: -240px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-gd {
    background-position: -128px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-dj {
    background-position: -48px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-ss {
    background-position: -128px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-gt {
    background-position: -80px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-sk {
    background-position: -16px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-sm {
    background-position: -48px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-bd {
    background-position: -16px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-jo {
    background-position: -208px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-iq {
    background-position: -96px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-bt {
    background-position: -208px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-it {
    background-position: -144px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-mg {
    background-position: -128px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-sr {
    background-position: -112px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-sg {
    background-position: -224px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-ec {
    background-position: -128px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-ge {
    background-position: -144px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-ie {
    background-position: 0 -66px;
}

.flag.flag-kz {
    background-position: -144px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-tc {
    background-position: -224px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-tg {
    background-position: 0 -143px;
}

.flag.flag-lv {
    background-position: -32px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-mo {
    background-position: -224px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-mv {
    background-position: -64px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-sz {
    background-position: -208px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-va {
    background-position: -48px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-bn {
    background-position: -144px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-bj {
    background-position: -112px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-zm {
    background-position: -16px -165px;
}

.flag.flag-co {
    background-position: -192px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-mn {
    background-position: -208px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-zw {
    background-position: -32px -165px;
}

.flag.flag-vn {
    background-position: -128px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-sl {
    background-position: -32px -132px;
}

.flag.flag-gi {
    background-position: -224px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-as {
    background-position: -160px 0;
}

.flag.flag-catalonia {
    background-position: -32px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-gb {
    background-position: -112px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-gl {
    background-position: -240px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-england {
    background-position: -192px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-py {
    background-position: -16px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-th {
    background-position: -16px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-eu {
    background-position: -256px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-zanzibar {
    background-position: 0 -165px;
}

.flag.flag-ch {
    background-position: -96px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-km {
    background-position: -32px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-om {
    background-position: -64px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-et {
    background-position: -240px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-fm {
    background-position: -48px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-ve {
    background-position: -80px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-io {
    background-position: -80px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-bm {
    background-position: -128px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-lk {
    background-position: -224px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-ye {
    background-position: -224px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-ms {
    background-position: -16px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-is {
    background-position: -128px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-hu {
    background-position: -224px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-rs {
    background-position: -80px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-md {
    background-position: -96px -88px;
}

.flag.flag-hn {
    background-position: -176px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-ne {
    background-position: -176px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-mt {
    background-position: -32px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-ng {
    background-position: -208px -99px;
}

.flag.flag-kg {
    background-position: -256px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-je {
    background-position: -176px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-in {
    background-position: -64px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-hr {
    background-position: -192px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-hm {
    background-position: -160px -55px;
}

.flag.flag-cm {
    background-position: -160px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-uz {
    background-position: -32px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-wales {
    background-position: -160px -154px;
}

.flag.flag-gm {
    background-position: -256px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-li {
    background-position: -208px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-nz {
    background-position: -48px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-bo {
    background-position: -160px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-se {
    background-position: -208px -121px;
}

.flag.flag-tm {
    background-position: -96px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-cg {
    background-position: -80px -22px;
}

.flag.flag-ir {
    background-position: -112px -66px;
}

.flag.flag-dk {
    background-position: -64px -33px;
}

.flag.flag-gf {
    background-position: -160px -44px;
}

.flag.flag-bi {
    background-position: -96px -11px;
}

.flag.flag-pe {
    background-position: -96px -110px;
}

.flag.flag-ua {
    background-position: -224px -143px;
}

.flag.flag-af {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

.flag.flag-ls {
    background-position: -256px -77px;
}

.flag.flag-lt {
    background-position: 0 -88px;
}
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <style>
            body { 
                font-family: Lato;
                background-color: #F5F5F5; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1 class="text-center title">Countries linked by Border</h1>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div id="results"></div>
                    <div id="flags"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
   <script type="text/javascript">
       
       // Acknowledgements:
       
       // Excelent D3 V4 tutorial: http://www.puzzlr.org/force-graphs-with-d3/
       
       // Drag Example: https://github.com/jenovs/chingu-fcc-speedrun-challenge/blob/master/data-vis/force-directed-graph/src/components/ForceGraph/ForceGraph.js
       
       
    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DealPete/forceDirected/master/countries.json", function(error, json) {

          if (error) {
            return console.warn(error);
          }

          const data = json;
          const nodes = data.nodes;
          const links = data.links;
     
            const margin = {
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0
            }

            const w = 1250 - margin.left - margin.right;
            const h = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
            const results = d3.select('#results')

            const svg = results.append("svg")
              .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

            const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                .nodes(nodes)
                .force("charge_force", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-3))
                .force("center_force", d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2));
        
            const div = d3.select("body")
                .append("div") 
                .attr("class", "tooltip")    
                .style("opacity", 0);

            const link = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "links")
              .selectAll("line")
              .data(links)
              .enter().append("line")
              .attr('stroke', 'black')
              .attr("stroke-width", 2);

            const node = results.select('#flags').selectAll('.node')
                .data(data.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append('img')
                .attr('class', d => 'flag flag-' + d.code)
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {  
                div.transition()  
                    .duration(200)  
                    .style("opacity", .9);  
                div .html(d.country) 
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 7) + "px")  
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px"); 
                })     
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {  
                div.transition()  
                    .duration(500)  
                    .style("opacity", 0); 
                }).call(d3.drag()
                .on('start', dragStarted)
                .on('drag', dragged)
                .on('end', dragEnded));

            const link_force = d3.forceLink(links)

            simulation.force("links", link_force)

            simulation.on("tick", tickActions);

            function tickActions() {
              node
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
                });

              link
                .attr("x1", function(d) {
                  return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function(d) {
                  return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function(d) {
                  return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function(d) {
                  return d.target.y;
                });
            }
        
            function dragStarted(d) {
                if (!d3.event.active) sim.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }

            function dragged(d) {
                d.fx = d3.event.x;
                d.fy = d3.event.y;
            }

            function dragEnded(d) {
                if (!d3.event.active) sim.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }

        });
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: Why didn't you use Stack Snippet?

Comment: The 7th button from the left is for the snippet editor. It's to the right of the image button.

Comment: `.attr("class", (d) => "flag flag-" + d.code)` seems like it would take existing class values (say `class='banana'`) and change them to, say, `class='flag flag.banana'`.  Is that what you were going for?  I'm not sure where the `code` property comes from, like `'banana'.code == undefined`, no?

Comment: Your code isn't working because you are attempting to mix `html`, `css` and `svg` without really understanding how these things mix (or in your case don't mix).  Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39129790/16363) I answered last year.  I still believe it's the correct way to do what you want.

Comment: What is `node` expected to be within `tickActions`?

Comment: `but don't see how it's related to my question`, huh?  flag sprites in a `d3` force layout?  Isn't that what you are trying to do....

Comment: I apologize if I sound harsh.  The question I linked to is the answer to your question (see below with it running in your code base).  I see too many people on these forums desperate for someone/anyone to fix their problems for them instead of attempting to learn how to solve their problems for themselves.  Might just be time for me to take a long break from StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes are made to the code and seem to be working now.

1. Position attribute of the div containing flags and flag class is set to absolute.
2. `<img>` tag was appended twice. Removed extra code.
3. Typo error - Change `sim` to `simulation` in dragstart and dragend methods.
4. `flags` div is not inside svg. So  change from `result.select("#flags")` to `d3.select("#flags")`

   etc.

```js
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DealPete/forceDirected/master/countries.json", function(error, json) {

  if (error) {
    return console.warn(error);
  }

  const data = json;
  const nodes = data.nodes;
  const links = data.links;

  const margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  }

  const w = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right;
  const h = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const results = d3.select('#results')

  const svg = results.append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .force("charge_force", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-3))
    .force("center_force", d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2));

  const div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

  const link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);

  const node = d3.select('#flags').selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('img')
    .attr('class', d => 'flag flag-' + d.code)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
      div.html(d.country)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 7) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    }).call(d3.drag()
      .on('start', dragStarted)
      .on('drag', dragged)
      .on('end', dragEnded))



  const link_force = d3.forceLink(links)

  simulation.force("links", link_force)

  simulation.on("tick", tickActions);

  function tickActions() {
    node.style('left', d => (d.x + 6) + "px")
      .style('top', d => (d.y - 5) + "px");

    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });
  }

  function dragStarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragEnded(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Lato;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#results {
  text-align: center;
}

#flags {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#results {
  background-color: white;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 550px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}

div.tooltip {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: black;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/*!
     * Generated with CSS Flag Sprite generator (https://www.flag-sprites.com/)
     */

.flag {
  width: 16px;
  height: 11px;
  background: url(https://www.cs.mun.ca/~h65ped/Public/country%20data%20for%20force%20directed%20graph/flags.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}

.flags {
  position: absolute;
}

.flag.flag-ad {
  background-position: -16px 0
}

.flag.flag-ae {
  background-position: -32px 0
}

.flag.flag-af {
  background-position: -48px 0
}

.flag.flag-ag {
  background-position: -64px 0
}

.flag.flag-ai {
  background-position: -80px 0
}

.flag.flag-al {
  background-position: -96px 0
}

.flag.flag-am {
  background-position: -112px 0
}

.flag.flag-an {
  background-position: -128px 0
}

.flag.flag-ao {
  background-position: -144px 0
}

.flag.flag-ar {
  background-position: -160px 0
}

.flag.flag-as {
  background-position: -176px 0
}

.flag.flag-at {
  background-position: -192px 0
}

.flag.flag-au {
  background-position: -208px 0
}

.flag.flag-aw {
  background-position: -224px 0
}

.flag.flag-az {
  background-position: -240px 0
}

.flag.flag-ba {
  background-position: 0 -11px
}

.flag.flag-bb {
  background-position: -16px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bd {
  background-position: -32px -11px
}

.flag.flag-be {
  background-position: -48px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bf {
  background-position: -64px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bg {
  background-position: -80px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bh {
  background-position: -96px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bi {
  background-position: -112px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bj {
  background-position: -128px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bm {
  background-position: -144px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bn {
  background-position: -160px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bo {
  background-position: -176px -11px
}

.flag.flag-br {
  background-position: -192px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bs {
  background-position: -208px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bt {
  background-position: -224px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bv {
  background-position: -240px -11px
}

.flag.flag-bw {
  background-position: 0 -22px
}

.flag.flag-by {
  background-position: -16px -22px
}

.flag.flag-bz {
  background-position: -32px -22px
}

.flag.flag-ca {
  background-position: -48px -22px
}

.flag.flag-catalonia {
  background-position: -64px -22px
}

.flag.flag-cd {
  background-position: -80px -22px
}

.flag.flag-cf {
  background-position: -96px -22px
}

.flag.flag-cg {
  background-position: -112px -22px
}

.flag.flag-ch {
  background-position: -128px -22px
}

.flag.flag-ci {
  background-position: -144px -22px
}

.flag.flag-ck {
  background-position: -160px -22px
}

.flag.flag-cl {
  background-position: -176px -22px
}

.flag.flag-cm {
  background-position: -192px -22px
}

.flag.flag-cn {
  background-position: -208px -22px
}

.flag.flag-co {
  background-position: -224px -22px
}

.flag.flag-cr {
  background-position: -240px -22px
}

.flag.flag-cu {
  background-position: 0 -33px
}

.flag.flag-cv {
  background-position: -16px -33px
}

.flag.flag-cw {
  background-position: -32px -33px
}

.flag.flag-cy {
  background-position: -48px -33px
}

.flag.flag-cz {
  background-position: -64px -33px
}

.flag.flag-de {
  background-position: -80px -33px
}

.flag.flag-dj {
  background-position: -96px -33px
}

.flag.flag-dk {
  background-position: -112px -33px
}

.flag.flag-dm {
  background-position: -128px -33px
}

.flag.flag-do {
  background-position: -144px -33px
}

.flag.flag-dz {
  background-position: -160px -33px
}

.flag.flag-ec {
  background-position: -176px -33px
}

.flag.flag-ee {
  background-position: -192px -33px
}

.flag.flag-eg {
  background-position: -208px -33px
}

.flag.flag-eh {
  background-position: -224px -33px
}

.flag.flag-england {
  background-position: -240px -33px
}

.flag.flag-er {
  background-position: 0 -44px
}

.flag.flag-es {
  background-position: -16px -44px
}

.flag.flag-et {
  background-position: -32px -44px
}

.flag.flag-eu {
  background-position: -48px -44px
}

.flag.flag-fi {
  background-position: -64px -44px
}

.flag.flag-fj {
  background-position: -80px -44px
}

.flag.flag-fk {
  background-position: -96px -44px
}

.flag.flag-fm {
  background-position: -112px -44px
}

.flag.flag-fo {
  background-position: -128px -44px
}

.flag.flag-fr {
  background-position: -144px -44px
}

.flag.flag-ga {
  background-position: -160px -44px
}

.flag.flag-gb {
  background-position: -176px -44px
}

.flag.flag-gd {
  background-position: -192px -44px
}

.flag.flag-ge {
  background-position: -208px -44px
}

.flag.flag-gf {
  background-position: -224px -44px
}

.flag.flag-gg {
  background-position: -240px -44px
}

.flag.flag-gh {
  background-position: 0 -55px
}

.flag.flag-gi {
  background-position: -16px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gl {
  background-position: -32px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gm {
  background-position: -48px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gn {
  background-position: -64px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gp {
  background-position: -80px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gq {
  background-position: -96px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gr {
  background-position: -112px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gs {
  background-position: -128px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gt {
  background-position: -144px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gu {
  background-position: -160px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gw {
  background-position: -176px -55px
}

.flag.flag-gy {
  background-position: -192px -55px
}

.flag.flag-hk {
  background-position: -208px -55px
}

.flag.flag-hm {
  background-position: -224px -55px
}

.flag.flag-hn {
  background-position: -240px -55px
}

.flag.flag-hr {
  background-position: 0 -66px
}

.flag.flag-ht {
  background-position: -16px -66px
}

.flag.flag-hu {
  background-position: -32px -66px
}

.flag.flag-ic {
  background-position: -48px -66px
}

.flag.flag-id {
  background-position: -64px -66px
}

.flag.flag-ie {
  background-position: -80px -66px
}

.flag.flag-il {
  background-position: -96px -66px
}

.flag.flag-im {
  background-position: -112px -66px
}

.flag.flag-in {
  background-position: -128px -66px
}

.flag.flag-io {
  background-position: -144px -66px
}

.flag.flag-iq {
  background-position: -160px -66px
}

.flag.flag-ir {
  background-position: -176px -66px
}

.flag.flag-is {
  background-position: -192px -66px
}

.flag.flag-it {
  background-position: -208px -66px
}

.flag.flag-je {
  background-position: -224px -66px
}

.flag.flag-jm {
  background-position: -240px -66px
}

.flag.flag-jo {
  background-position: 0 -77px
}

.flag.flag-jp {
  background-position: -16px -77px
}

.flag.flag-ke {
  background-position: -32px -77px
}

.flag.flag-kg {
  background-position: -48px -77px
}

.flag.flag-kh {
  background-position: -64px -77px
}

.flag.flag-ki {
  background-position: -80px -77px
}

.flag.flag-km {
  background-position: -96px -77px
}

.flag.flag-kn {
  background-position: -112px -77px
}

.flag.flag-kp {
  background-position: -128px -77px
}

.flag.flag-kr {
  background-position: -144px -77px
}

.flag.flag-kurdistan {
  background-position: -160px -77px
}

.flag.flag-kw {
  background-position: -176px -77px
}

.flag.flag-ky {
  background-position: -192px -77px
}

.flag.flag-kz {
  background-position: -208px -77px
}

.flag.flag-la {
  background-position: -224px -77px
}

.flag.flag-lb {
  background-position: -240px -77px
}

.flag.flag-lc {
  background-position: 0 -88px
}

.flag.flag-li {
  background-position: -16px -88px
}

.flag.flag-lk {
  background-position: -32px -88px
}

.flag.flag-lr {
  background-position: -48px -88px
}

.flag.flag-ls {
  background-position: -64px -88px
}

.flag.flag-lt {
  background-position: -80px -88px
}

.flag.flag-lu {
  background-position: -96px -88px
}

.flag.flag-lv {
  background-position: -112px -88px
}

.flag.flag-ly {
  background-position: -128px -88px
}

.flag.flag-ma {
  background-position: -144px -88px
}

.flag.flag-mc {
  background-position: -160px -88px
}

.flag.flag-md {
  background-position: -176px -88px
}

.flag.flag-me {
  background-position: -192px -88px
}

.flag.flag-mg {
  background-position: -208px -88px
}

.flag.flag-mh {
  background-position: -224px -88px
}

.flag.flag-mk {
  background-position: -240px -88px
}

.flag.flag-ml {
  background-position: 0 -99px
}

.flag.flag-mm {
  background-position: -16px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mn {
  background-position: -32px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mo {
  background-position: -48px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mp {
  background-position: -64px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mq {
  background-position: -80px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mr {
  background-position: -96px -99px
}

.flag.flag-ms {
  background-position: -112px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mt {
  background-position: -128px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mu {
  background-position: -144px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mv {
  background-position: -160px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mw {
  background-position: -176px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mx {
  background-position: -192px -99px
}

.flag.flag-my {
  background-position: -208px -99px
}

.flag.flag-mz {
  background-position: -224px -99px
}

.flag.flag-na {
  background-position: -240px -99px
}

.flag.flag-nc {
  background-position: 0 -110px
}

.flag.flag-ne {
  background-position: -16px -110px
}

.flag.flag-nf {
  background-position: -32px -110px
}

.flag.flag-ng {
  background-position: -48px -110px
}

.flag.flag-ni {
  background-position: -64px -110px
}

.flag.flag-nl {
  background-position: -80px -110px
}

.flag.flag-no {
  background-position: -96px -110px
}

.flag.flag-np {
  background-position: -112px -110px
}

.flag.flag-nr {
  background-position: -128px -110px
}

.flag.flag-nu {
  background-position: -144px -110px
}

.flag.flag-nz {
  background-position: -160px -110px
}

.flag.flag-om {
  background-position: -176px -110px
}

.flag.flag-pa {
  background-position: -192px -110px
}

.flag.flag-pe {
  background-position: -208px -110px
}

.flag.flag-pf {
  background-position: -224px -110px
}

.flag.flag-pg {
  background-position: -240px -110px
}

.flag.flag-ph {
  background-position: 0 -121px
}

.flag.flag-pk {
  background-position: -16px -121px
}

.flag.flag-pl {
  background-position: -32px -121px
}

.flag.flag-pm {
  background-position: -48px -121px
}

.flag.flag-pn {
  background-position: -64px -121px
}

.flag.flag-pr {
  background-position: -80px -121px
}

.flag.flag-ps {
  background-position: -96px -121px
}

.flag.flag-pt {
  background-position: -112px -121px
}

.flag.flag-pw {
  background-position: -128px -121px
}

.flag.flag-py {
  background-position: -144px -121px
}

.flag.flag-qa {
  background-position: -160px -121px
}

.flag.flag-re {
  background-position: -176px -121px
}

.flag.flag-ro {
  background-position: -192px -121px
}

.flag.flag-rs {
  background-position: -208px -121px
}

.flag.flag-ru {
  background-position: -224px -121px
}

.flag.flag-rw {
  background-position: -240px -121px
}

.flag.flag-sa {
  background-position: 0 -132px
}

.flag.flag-sb {
  background-position: -16px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sc {
  background-position: -32px -132px
}

.flag.flag-scotland {
  background-position: -48px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sd {
  background-position: -64px -132px
}

.flag.flag-se {
  background-position: -80px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sg {
  background-position: -96px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sh {
  background-position: -112px -132px
}

.flag.flag-si {
  background-position: -128px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sk {
  background-position: -144px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sl {
  background-position: -160px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sm {
  background-position: -176px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sn {
  background-position: -192px -132px
}

.flag.flag-so {
  background-position: -208px -132px
}

.flag.flag-somaliland {
  background-position: -224px -132px
}

.flag.flag-sr {
  background-position: -240px -132px
}

.flag.flag-ss {
  background-position: 0 -143px
}

.flag.flag-st {
  background-position: -16px -143px
}

.flag.flag-sv {
  background-position: -32px -143px
}

.flag.flag-sx {
  background-position: -48px -143px
}

.flag.flag-sy {
  background-position: -64px -143px
}

.flag.flag-sz {
  background-position: -80px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tc {
  background-position: -96px -143px
}

.flag.flag-td {
  background-position: -112px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tf {
  background-position: -128px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tg {
  background-position: -144px -143px
}

.flag.flag-th {
  background-position: -160px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tibet {
  background-position: -176px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tj {
  background-position: -192px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tk {
  background-position: -208px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tl {
  background-position: -224px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tm {
  background-position: -240px -143px
}

.flag.flag-tn {
  background-position: 0 -154px
}

.flag.flag-to {
  background-position: -16px -154px
}

.flag.flag-tr {
  background-position: -32px -154px
}

.flag.flag-tt {
  background-position: -48px -154px
}

.flag.flag-tv {
  background-position: -64px -154px
}

.flag.flag-tw {
  background-position: -80px -154px
}

.flag.flag-tz {
  background-position: -96px -154px
}

.flag.flag-ua {
  background-position: -112px -154px
}

.flag.flag-ug {
  background-position: -128px -154px
}

.flag.flag-um {
  background-position: -144px -154px
}

.flag.flag-us {
  background-position: -160px -154px
}

.flag.flag-uy {
  background-position: -176px -154px
}

.flag.flag-uz {
  background-position: -192px -154px
}

.flag.flag-va {
  background-position: -208px -154px
}

.flag.flag-vc {
  background-position: -224px -154px
}

.flag.flag-ve {
  background-position: -240px -154px
}

.flag.flag-vg {
  background-position: 0 -165px
}

.flag.flag-vi {
  background-position: -16px -165px
}

.flag.flag-vn {
  background-position: -32px -165px
}

.flag.flag-vu {
  background-position: -48px -165px
}

.flag.flag-wales {
  background-position: -64px -165px
}

.flag.flag-wf {
  background-position: -80px -165px
}

.flag.flag-ws {
  background-position: -96px -165px
}

.flag.flag-xk {
  background-position: -112px -165px
}

.flag.flag-ye {
  background-position: -128px -165px
}

.flag.flag-yt {
  background-position: -144px -165px
}

.flag.flag-za {
  background-position: -160px -165px
}

.flag.flag-zanzibar {
  background-position: -176px -165px
}

.flag.flag-zm {
  background-position: -192px -165px
}

.flag.flag-zw {
  background-position: -208px -165px
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Lato;
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="text-center title">Countries linked by Border</h1>
      <div class="text-center">
        <div id="flags"></div>
        <div id="results"></div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code above you are attempting to parent an **HTML** `img` tag to an **SVG** parent.  **This will never work**.  In the question I linked to in the comments, that OP attempted to solve this problem by using the `foreignObject` tag (which then allows HTML content inside it).  As you mentioned, this is evil and should be avoided.  So, my solution in the linked question was to set up some svg [patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns) that allow you to take your single sprite image and transform it to the proper coordinates for each flag.  Here is that approach with your code base...

[Full code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LyJvgNfcutKmvmsdgro5?p=preview) (that stack snippet was too big so I had to remove some flags).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Lato;
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="text-center title">Countries linked by Border</h1>
      <div class="text-center">
        <div id="results"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DealPete/forceDirected/master/countries.json", function(error, json) {

          if (error) {
            return console.warn(error);
          }

          const data = json;
          const nodes = data.nodes;
          const links = data.links;

          var imagePos = [{
              "c": "td",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "pw",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "fk",
              "x": -32,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "im",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "fr",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "sh",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "bg",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "ly",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "tk",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "re",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "nl",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "sv",
              "x": -160,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "sa",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "ck",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "tr",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "pr",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "tv",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "sd",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "uy",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "bb",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "za",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "vu",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "ba",
              "x": -256,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "kr",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "tf",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "cl",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "ki",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "lr",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "do",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "dz",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "cr",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "ar",
              "x": -144,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "sb",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "tj",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "cw",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "bv",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "pn",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "so",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "la",
              "x": -160,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "me",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "sx",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "sy",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "gq",
              "x": -32,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "ro",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "ku",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "si",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "mh",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "ky",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "eh",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "ru",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "tz",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "np",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "pg",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "lb",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "sn",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "gw",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "tt",
              "x": -160,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "eg",
              "x": -160,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "gn",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "al",
              "x": -80,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "jm",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "be",
              "x": -32,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "kn",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "mu",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "az",
              "x": -240,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "gh",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "vg",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "ug",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "rw",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "pl",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "at",
              "x": -176,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "bs",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "ee",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "no",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "ca",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "ml",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "vc",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "mc",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "vi",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "fj",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "sj",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "ic",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "fo",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "lu",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "nf",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "mm",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "er",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "so",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "lc",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "cd",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "ma",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "mp",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "mx",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "na",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "gs",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "tw",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "ae",
              "x": -16,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "cu",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "id",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "ht",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "kw",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "by",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "il",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "ps",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "tl",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "ai",
              "x": -64,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "gp",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "pt",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "gr",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "bw",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "kp",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "mq",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "ad",
              "x": 0,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "gu",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "cf",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "ni",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "ke",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "mz",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "kh",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "us",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "wf",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "hk",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "ph",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "de",
              "x": -32,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "sc",
              "x": -160,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "ti",
              "x": -32,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "cy",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "sc",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "ws",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "ci",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "bf",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "tn",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "my",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "mw",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "an",
              "x": -112,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "nr",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "pm",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "xk",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "es",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "pa",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "jp",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "mr",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "pf",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "cn",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "au",
              "x": -192,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "cv",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "ao",
              "x": -128,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "fi",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "nc",
              "x": -160,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "ag",
              "x": -48,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "gy",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "nu",
              "x": -32,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "to",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "qa",
              "x": -32,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "dm",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "aw",
              "x": -208,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "cz",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "mk",
              "x": -160,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "ax",
              "x": -224,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "pk",
              "x": -160,
              "y": -110
            }, {
              "c": "st",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "bz",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -22
            }, {
              "c": "br",
              "x": -176,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "am",
              "x": -96,
              "y": 0
            }, {
              "c": "bh",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "gg",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "um",
              "x": -256,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "ga",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "yt",
              "x": -240,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "gd",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "dj",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "ss",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "gt",
              "x": -80,
              "y": -55
            }, {
              "c": "sk",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "sm",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "bd",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "jo",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "iq",
              "x": -96,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "bt",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "it",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "mg",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "sr",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "sg",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -121
            }, {
              "c": "ec",
              "x": -128,
              "y": -33
            }, {
              "c": "ge",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -44
            }, {
              "c": "ie",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -66
            }, {
              "c": "kz",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -77
            }, {
              "c": "tc",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "tg",
              "x": 0,
              "y": -143
            }, {
              "c": "lv",
              "x": -32,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "mo",
              "x": -224,
              "y": -88
            }, {
              "c": "mv",
              "x": -64,
              "y": -99
            }, {
              "c": "sz",
              "x": -208,
              "y": -132
            }, {
              "c": "va",
              "x": -48,
              "y": -154
            }, {
              "c": "bn",
              "x": -144,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "bj",
              "x": -112,
              "y": -11
            }, {
              "c": "zm",
              "x": -16,
              "y": -165
            }, {
              "c": "co",
              "x": -192,
              "y": -22
            }];

            const margin = {
              top: 10,
              right: 85,
              bottom: 65,
              left: 70
            }

            const w = 1250 - margin.left - margin.right;
            const h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            const svg = d3.select("#results")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
              .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

            var defs = svg.append("defs")
              .selectAll("pattern")
              .data(imagePos)
              .enter()
              .append("pattern")
              .attr("width", 16)
              .attr("height", 11)
              .attr("id", function(d) {
                return "pattern_" + d.c;
              });

            defs.append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "https://image.ibb.co/gMUNBQ/flags.png")
            .attr("x", (d) => d.x)
            .attr("y", (d) => d.y)
            .attr("width", "272")
            .attr("height", "176");

            const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
              .nodes(nodes);

            simulation
            .force("charge_force", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-3))
            .force("center_force", d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2));

            const link = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "links")
              .selectAll("line")
              .data(links)
              .enter().append("line")
              .attr('stroke', 'black')
              .attr("stroke-width", 2);

            const node = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "nodes")
              .selectAll("g")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter()
              .append("g")

            node.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("Y", 0)
            .attr("width", 16)
            .attr("height", 11)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
              return "url(#pattern_" + d.code + ")";
            });

            const link_force = d3.forceLink(links)

            simulation.force("links", link_force)

            simulation.on("tick", tickActions);

            function tickActions() {
              node
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
                });

              link
                .attr("x1", function(d) {
                  return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function(d) {
                  return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function(d) {
                  return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function(d) {
                  return d.target.y;
                });
            }

          });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello ! It seems there is a mistake somewhere ? Sweden does not share a border with those 2 countries to my knowledge (Check on the right). There also a few other similar mistakes and even flags that are present twice ?

Comment: @Coder1000, hmm, looks like the image is pattern wrapping after 100 pixels on the x/y using a patterTransform.  I modified the implementation, see if that looks better.

Comment: Great, now it works ! Also, would you like to try to also give an answer closer to the reference one (without the js for each flag) for the bounty :D ?

Comment: @Coder1000, your "reference implementation" is using **HTML**.  You are using **SVG**; things just don't work the same between the two.  If I knew a "better" way of doing what you are after, trust me, I would have offered it by now.